# pandas datetime to unixtime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, unix-timestamp

I want to change Datetime (2014-12-23 00:00:00) into unixtime. I tried it with the Datetime function but it didn´t work. I got the Datetime stamps in an array.

```
Zeit =np.array(Jahresgang1.ix[ :,'Zeitstempel'])
t = pd.to_datetime(Zeit, unit='s')
unixtime = pd.DataFrame(t)
print unixtime
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Assuming that your dtype is `datetime64` then the following seems to do what you want: `(t.astype(np.int64) / 1e6).astype(np.uint64)`

Comment: Another method is: `(t - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: Thanks so much again and again. You have alsways the right answers for me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can subtract the date `1970-1-1` to create a `timedelta` and then access the attribute [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html#pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds):

```
In [130]:    
s = pd.Series(pd.datetime(2012,1,1))
s

Out[130]:
0   2012-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [158]:
(s - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()

Out[158]:
0    1325376000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: How can i add 1h to the unixtime, because i live in UTC:+1h

Comment: You can add a timedelta prior to the calculations above: `s + pd.Timedelta(1,'h')` or in your case `t + pd.Timedelta(1,'h')`

Comment: Actually the correct way would be to make the datetimes timezone aware, e.g. `s.dt.tz_localize('utc')` or whatever timezone you want

Comment: @EdChum You can also get this with the datetime.timestamp() method.

Answer (score 0):

to emphasize EdChum's first comment, you can directly get Unix time like

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.to_datetime(["2014-12-23 00:00:00"])
unix = s.astype("int64")

print(unix)
# Int64Index([1419292800000000000], dtype='int64')
```

or for a pd.Timestamp:

```py
print(pd.to_datetime("2014-12-23 00:00:00").value)
# 1419292800000000000
```

***Notes***

- the output precision is nanoseconds - if you want another, divide appropriately, e.g. by 10⁹ to get seconds, 10⁶ to get milliseconds etc.
- this assumes the input date/time to be UTC, unless a time zone / UTC offset is specified