# Column from date time to Unix time-stamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a data frame in `pandas` with a single column called `Time_column`.

This column is of `datetime64` datatype. Now I want to convert this column to `unix timestamp`

```
           Time_column
0  2017-03-12 02:43:52
1  2017-03-12 02:56:32
2  2017-03-12 02:56:32
3  2017-03-12 03:16:23
4  2017-03-12 03:17:15
5  2017-03-12 03:22:19
6  2017-03-12 03:22:19
7  2017-03-12 03:33:07
8  2017-03-12 03:33:07
9  2017-03-12 03:43:16
10 2017-03-12 03:43:16
```

How can I do that?

I have tried like below

```
import datetime
t = datetime.datetime(2018, 01, 30, 0, 0)
(t-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
1517270400.0
```

I am able to do this for one record. How can I apply this for a column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas datetime to unixtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038273/pandas-datetime-to-unixtime)

Comment: @FObersteiner Are you serious? commenting on a post after 4 and half years

Comment: And you're still responding :) Well, I found your question, and actually I wanted to link the other question because I think the answer here is pretty convoluted. I've even added an answer to the other question which is 6 years old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `apply`

```
#df.Time_column=pd.to_datetime(df.Time_column)

df.Time_column.apply(lambda x : (x-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
```